# Checking for equality in Angular filter

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have objects similar to the ones listed below:

```
fields = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
rules: [{name: "A", field: {id: 1}}, {name: "B", field: {id: 2}}]
```

And I want to filter each of the rules out by individual field IDs. Right now I have:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in fields">
    <h4>{{f.id}}</h4>
    <li ng-repeat = "rule in rules | filter: {field.id: f.id}">
        {{rule.name}}
    </li>
</div>
```

However, the following filter returns no elements. How do I make the filter show the rules that have field.id equal to f.id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in fields">
    <h4>{{f.id}}</h4>
    <li ng-repeat = "rule in rules | filter:{ field: {id: f.id} }">
        {{rule.name}}
    </li>
</div>
```

Match the object structure in the filter.

Here is the [**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dMBNq3TEILIxAqdP6qzo?p=preview) where I have added another property `age` (int) to prove the fact that filter only works on `id`.

Comment: So it turns out this filter doesn't work for matching ids with multiple digits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333209/angular-filter-checks-for-contains-and-not-equals