# Angular filter checks for 'contains' and not 'equals'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to match rules to fields using the 'filter' filter in Angular as shown here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dQiv5lRzhQNjXZ6pVdWO?p=preview

I'm using the filter as shown below:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in fields">
      <h4>{{f.id}}</h4>
      <li ng-repeat = "rule in rules | filter:{field: {id: f.id} }">
        {{rule.name}}
      </li>
    </div>
```

This works fine with single digit ids, but with two digits, as shown below:

```
$scope.fields = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];
$scope.rules = [{name: "A", field: {id: 12, age: 3}}, {name: "B", field: {id: 2, age: 1}}];
```

The rule with id 12 gets matched to the fields with ids of 1 and 2, when it should only get matched to fields of id 12. Is there a way to do this with the default filter, or should I create a custom filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own filter:

```
.filter('byId',function(){
  return function(items, id){
    var res = [];
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
      if(items[i].field.id===id){
        res.push(items[i]);
      }  
    }
    return res;
  };
});
```

Html:

```
<li ng-repeat = "rule in rules | byId:f.id">
  {{rule.name}}
</li>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/d3jmMWOwsHlMEya2Kjei?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I've found this article that solved the problem 
[Angular JS filter equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934800/angular-js-filter-equals)

In your case you should write:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in fields">
      <h4>{{f.id}}</h4>
      <li ng-repeat = "rule in rules | filter:{field: {id: f.id} }:true">
        {{rule.name}}
      </li>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular supports Equals match natively. in place of comparator function, just pass "true". By default it is false.

In HTML Template Binding

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : true }}
```

In JavaScript

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, true)
```

Refer: [Angular Js Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)