# Angular JS filter equals

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Please see the details. Why is the output wrong?

HTML:

```html
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
         <h1>List</h1>

        <div ng-repeat="t in todos | filter:{ id: '-1'}">{{t.text}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular code:

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.todos = [{
        text: 'learn angular',
        done: true,
        id: -1
    },{
        text: 'learn angular 2',
        done: true,
        id: -11
    }, {
        text: 'build an angular app',
        done: false,
        id: 1
    }];
}
```

Output:

```js
learn angular
learn angular 2
```

Please see:

> filter:{ id: '-1'}

Why does the output include:

```js
learn angular 2
```

I want to search the id `-1`, but `learn angular 2` is `-11`

Answer (score 25):

Remove the quotes from '-1' and send `true` to the filter to do a strict comparison.

> `ng-repeat="t in todos | filter:{ id: -1}:true"`

Comment: Why does this happen?

Comment: what if i want  not equal to -1 values with :true ??

Comment: can you help for this `http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/33383/` , why last one is not display in output , event there is id is -12 ?