# AngularJS: how to filter only items that have specific 3 characters in value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am using the `ng-repeat` directive on an array of objects that contains values like the following:

```
{...,"Department": "ABC",...} // object 1
{...,"Department": "ABCDE",...} // object 2, etc
```

I only want to list the items that contain Department "ABC". But, when I do

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td>Department:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:{Department: 'ABC'}">
    <td>{{employee.Email}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.Department}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I get the listing of all values that contain "ABC" in the Department field, including those that start with ABC like so: "ABCDEF".

How would I limit the results to only show the items from the ABC Department and not any other Departments that may happen to have ABC as their first 3 characters? I tried "limitTo" , but that only limits the results, not characters. [Plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/I4gcq7nbIdCe6zqs3ur6?p=preview)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular JS filter equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934800/angular-js-filter-equals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the comparator argument for filter (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

The solution is to add `:true` to the filter:

```
employee in employees | filter:{Department: 'ABC'}:true
```

...for "strict comparison of expected and actual".

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you! A deeper read of the official docs always rewards the reader. Thanks.